# Grails 2.4 upgrade issues from 2.2 test event called at app startup

Tags: grails, testing, upgrade

At application startup the eventTestPhasesStart event code in _events script is being called.  The test classes referenced in the event code are not available when executing runapp which leads to classes not resolved errors at startup.

- unable to resolve class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.test.spock.GrailsSpecTestType
- unable to resolve class - org.codehaus.groovy.grails.test.junit4.JUnit4GrailsTestType
- unable to resolve class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.test.runner.phase.IntegrationTestPhaseConfigurer

This code also fails to run in forked mode which has forced us to turn forked mode off to run the integration tests which means we cannot use the debugger to debug tests as Grails 2.4 now requires.

The following is the event code:

eventTestPhasesStart = {phasesToRun ->
    println "setting inmem phase"
    phasesToRun << "inmem"

```
def inmemPhaseConfigurer = new IntegrationTestPhaseConfigurer(projectTestRunner.projectTestCompiler, projectLoader)
projectTestRunner.testFeatureDiscovery.configurers.inmem = inmemPhaseConfigurer

def inmemtestTypeName = "inmem"
def inmemtestDirectory = "inmem"
def inmemtestMode = new GrailsTestMode(autowire: true, wrapInTransaction: true, wrapInRequestEnvironment: true)


inmemTestTypes = []
inmemTestTypes << (new GrailsSpecTestType(inmemtestTypeName+"Spock", inmemtestDirectory, inmemtestMode))
inmemTestTypes << (new JUnit4GrailsTestType(inmemtestTypeName+"JUnit", inmemtestDirectory, inmemtestMode))

projectTestRunner.testFeatureDiscovery.testExecutionContext.inmemTests = inmemTestTypes
```

}

When running in forked mode this event is again called when/where it shouldn't resulting in the dynamic properties such as projectTestRunner not being found.

Is there a way to prevent this script from being executed when it shouldn't?

thank you

Comment: I have worked around the issue of the unresolved classes at startup by adding a compile dependency compile 'org.grails:grails-test:2.4.4'.  That was the easy part.  I'd really like to be able to have the custom test phase and be able to run the tests in forked mode to enable debugging of the test code.    Anyone have a clue?